# django-socialregistration access_token error

Tags: django, facebook, django-facebook

I've been currently trying to write a simple Django app with social platforms integration. I decided to use a plugin django-socialregistration to connect to facebook accounts. I followed the installation guide on http://django-socialregistration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ .

Application shows the button, after clicking it redirects to facebook login page, shows the request dialog and finally bails with the following error:

```
KeyError at /social/facebook/callback/

'access_token'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://somehost:8000/social/facebook/callback/?code=
[here comes long code]
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'access_token'

Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
django_socialregistration-0.5-py2.7.egg/socialregistration/clients/oauth.py in get_access_token, line 273
```

sorry for posting error-message-like question, but I have absolutely no idea how to solve it.

thanks a lot,

Tomek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm biased since I'm the author, but did you try:
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook
We use it quite a massive production environment, works very well.

Only an option if you only need facebook.